# Message polling instance ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, amazon-sqs, polling

Is there a way to know which instance is polling messages from a particular SQS Queue when there are multiple SQS Queues?
I need to know which instance is polling from the Queue to create tags.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently there is no easy way to tell which instances are polling from a specific queue since [SQS data events are not recored in CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html#logging-data-events).

Alternatives are

1. infer from the [last accessed information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_access-advisor.html#access_policies_access-advisor-data-types) of the IAM role attached to the EC2 instances
2. analyze the [VPC flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html)

Comment: Thank you. I will try these.